# Convert day of year to Date Format in Pyspark

Tags: date, pyspark, to-date, julian-date

I have a pySpark dataframe with a date column as `yyyyddd`, where `yyyy` is year(format 2020, 2021) and `ddd` is the day of year(format 001, 365, 366).

I am trying to convert it to date as:

```
df = df.withColumn("new_date", to_date("old_date", "yyyyddd"))
```

but this gives me the correct answer for January dates only, and 'Null' for all other months.

old_date is `StringType` and new_date is `DateType`

| old_date | new_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2006272 (means 272nd day of 2006) | null |
| 2008016 | 2008-01-16 |
| 2011179 | null |
| 2011026 | 2011-01-26 |

How can I convert this date format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `D` format which represents the `day of year` in `unix_timestamp` functions like below. You would not need `UDF` to perform this operation

```
# Import functions
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df.withColumn("new_date", f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp("old_date", 'yyyyD'),'yyyy-MMdd'))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind using a udf, you can use `datetime`

```
import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType

udf_todate = F.udf(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%j'), DateType())

df = df.withColumn("new_date", udf_todate("old_date"))
```